# Reverse numerical sorting for one column from output in Python

Tags: python

Please,help.
I have csv-file, which look like this:

```
435;fd;4

435;a;4

435;b lfdsk;2

435;c lfdsk;4

435;d;14

435;dsf;3

435;ad;4

435;fd;4
```

I can't to do reverse sort correctly for one (2-nd) column from my print.

It's my code

```
import csv
import collections

grades = collections.Counter()
with open('Ya.csv') as input_file:
    for row in csv.reader(input_file, delimiter=';'):
        grades[row[2]] += 1

print '\n'.join(('%s;%s' % (key, value) for key, value in grades.most_common()))
input_file.close()
```

Output:

```
4;5

3;1

2;1

14;1
```

Comment: You're simpy using the wrong array index. Index 2 means the 3rd field, thus you count the last column. And the output means you have 5 times the 4 as last column, one time a 3, one time a 2 and one time a 14

Comment: You don't need `input_file.close()` after a `with` block. That is what `with` blocks are for.

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak because my initial data-file has **3 cols**,

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @MartinEvans like my output, but only 2-nd column must need with reverse sorting!

Comment: Wrap your list in reversed() like so: reversed(grades.most_common())

Comment: "because my initial data-file has 3 cols". Right, but you ask about the second column, which you can access using index 1. Python lists start at 0, not at 1.

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply looking for sorting the records based on second column you can it as:

```
import csv

records = []
with open('Ya.csv') as input_file:
    for row in csv.reader(input_file, delimiter=';'):
        if len(row) == 3:
            records.append(row)

sorted_records = sorted(records, key=lambda record: int(record[2]), reverse=True)
print sorted_records
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just reverse the order returned from `most_common()` as follows:

```
import csv
import collections

grades = collections.Counter()

with open('Ya.csv') as input_file:
    for row in csv.reader(input_file, delimiter=';'):
        grades[row[2]] += 1

print '\n'.join(('%s;%s' % (key, value) for key, value in grades.most_common()[::-1]))
```

This would display your output as follows:

```
14;1
2;1
3;1
4;5
```

`[::-1]` has the effect of returning the list returned from `most_common` in the reverse order. As noted, using the `with` statement means the file will automatically be closed afterwards.

Comment: you are sort 1 col, not 2-nd column